# Managing composer and deployment

Tags: json, git, deployment, composer-php

So, I'm enjoying using composer, but I'm struggling to understand how others use it in relation to a deployment service. Currently I'm using deployhq, and yes, I can set it to deploy and run composer when there is an update to the repo, but this doesn't make sense to me now.

My main composer repo, containing just the json file of all of the packages I want to include in my build, only gets updated when I add a new package to the list.

When I update my theme, or custom extension (which is referenced in the json file), there is no "hook" to update my deployment service. So I have to log in to my server and manually run composer (which takes the site down until it's finished).

So how do others manage this? Should I only run composer locally and include the vendor folder in my repo?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

James

Answer (score 0):

There will always be arguments as to the best way to do things such as this and there are different answers and different options - the trick is to find the one that works best for you.

**Firstly**

I would first take a step back and look at how you are managing your composer.json

I would recommend that all of your packages in composer.json be locked down to the exact version number of the item in Packagist. If you are using github repo's for any of the packages (or they are set to dev-master) then I would ensure that these packages are locked to a specific commit hash! It sounds like you are basically there with this as you say nothing updates out of the packages when you run it.

**Why?**

This is to ensure that when you run composer update on the server, these packages are taken from the cache if they exist and to ensure that you dont accidentally deploy untested code if one of the modules happens to get updated between you testing and your deployment.

**Actual deployments**

*Possible Method 1*

My opinion is slightly controversial in that when it comes to Composer for many of my projects that don't go through a CI system, I will commit the entire vendor directory to version control. This is quite simply to ensure that I have a completely deployable branch at any stage, it also makes deployments incredibly quick and easy (git pull).

There will already be people saying that this is unnecessary and that locking down the version numbers will be enough to ensure any remote system failures will be handled, it clogs up the VCS tree etc etc - I won't go into these now, there are arguments for and against (a lot of it opinion based), but as you mentioned it in your question I thought I would let you know that it has served me well on a lot of projects in the past and it is a viable option.

*Possible Method 2*

By using symlinks on your server to your document root you can ensure that the build completes before you switch over the symlink to the new directory once you have confirmed the build completed.
This is the least resistance path towards a safe deployment for a basic code set using composer update on the server. I actually use this method in conjunction with most of my deployments (including the ones above and below).

*Possible Method 3*

Composer can use "artifacts" rather than a remote server, this will mean that you will basically be creating a "repository folder" of your vendor files, this is an alternative to adding the entire vendor folder into your VCS - but it also protects you against Github / Packagist outages / files being removed and various other potential issues. The files are retrieved from the artifacts folder and installed directly from the zip file rather than being retrieved from a server - this folder can be stored remotely - think of it as a poor mans private packagist (another option btw).

*IMO - The best method overall*

Set up a CI system (like Jenkins), create some tests for your application and have them respond to push webhooks on your VCS so it builds each time something is pushed. In this build you will set up the system to:

- run tests on your application (If they exist)
- run composer update
- generate an artifact of these files (if the above items succeed)

Jenkins can also do an actual deployment for you if you wish (and the build process doesn't fail), it can:

- push the artifact to the server via SSH
- deploy the artifact using a script

But if you already have a deployment system in place, having a tested artifact to be deployed will probably be one of its deployment scenarios.

Hope this helps :)